# export to excel with date period in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Please help me. I will export to excel with period time.

My controller:

```
function toExcelAll() {
    $query['data1'] = $this->m_laporanpembelian->ToExcelAll();
    $this->load->view('laporanpembelian/excel',$query);
}
```

My model :

```
function toExcelAll() {
    $this->db->select("id_pembelian,tgl_pembelian, total_pembelian");
    $this->db->from("hpembelian");
    $getData = $this->db->get();
    if ($getData->num_rows() > 0)
        return $getData->result_array();
    else
        return null;
}
```

i use bootstrap in front-end

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: i want to export data to excel with the period specified by the user, the script above for export all files. please help me

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think you have supplied enough info for us to be able to answer you.